# Can the scrolling increment that is used to zoom in/out in Visio be changed?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, microsoft-visio, scroll-wheel, microsoft-visio-2013

When I'm using CTRL + mouse wheel to zoom in/out in Visio, the jump in percentage of zoom is ludicrous. It jumps from 50% to 132% and then to 397%. It seems like there should be some middle ground there. I'm using a Microsoft mouse on Windows 7 and don't know if the mouse/driver is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your scroll wheel setting is way high.  Open Control Panel, then click on Mouse.  In the Wheel tab, change the Vertical Scrolling.  The default is 3 lines at a time, so that setting should work well.  From the sound of it, you probably have selected "One screen at a time".

Comment: I had a similar thought and checked that after posting the question. Unfortunately, the vertical scrolling in the wheel tab was already set to 1 line at a time.

Comment: Do you use any third-party mouse software?  I know KatMouse is known to have some issues with Visio.

Comment: No. Just a normal Microsoft wireless mouse with the standard driver.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not. Alternatively you can use ctrl+shift+left click to zoom in, and ctrl+shift+right click to zoom out. It is easier to control than the mouse wheel for me. I confirmed in Visio Standard 2019.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/zoom-and-pan-in-a-diagram-f9ee5535-7402-4e97-8b93-127e3ecbf027